# Continuos Signal handle

Tags: c++, signals

I am building an algorithm for handling signal received from RS232 port. The basic idea is to receive a signal from RS232 and then grab image with camera.

Let's ignore camera and RS232 for now. My short program should enter the while loop, and ask for "cin" command. If `command == 'b'`, signal should be raised and `signal_handler()` function activated. For now it works fine.

What I would like to do is change the program to get back into while loop and continue. My program is terminated after interupt.

When I remove `exit(signum)`, program returns into while loop and ask for the command. And if I enter 'b' again Program ends.

Where did I go wrong? Wrong signal or entire entire approach?
Thanks!

```
void signalHandler(int signum) {
    cout << "Interrupt signal (" << signum << ") received.\n";
}

int main(){
    char Command = 'a';

    signal(SIGINT, signalHandler);

    while (true){
        cout << "Command: ";
        cin >> Command;
        if (Command == 'b'){
            raise(SIGINT);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `SIGINT` (signal to interrupt), instead of one of the two user signals `SIGUSR1` or `SIGUSR2`?

Comment: Because I haven't heard about them, can you give example how should I implement them in my case?

Comment: Just the same, but with e.g. `SIGUSR1` instead. And is there really a *need* to use signals here? Why not simply call a function?

Comment: The thing is that I have an outside triger and he wont send signal in each tact. Only when PLC reads enough signals, he will triger the camera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're having is because one the signal is caught, the signal handler is *reset* to its default, which in the case of `SIGINT` is to terminate the process.

You should be using [`sigaction`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html) instead, which lets you specify the behavior (check the section about the `SA_RESETHAND` flag).